# Is boot history stored on motherboard?

Tags: boot, motherboard, macbook

I know that boot and login history is stored both on macOS (`/var/log/`) and Windows systems on the hard drive.

Now the MacBooks hard drive has been formatted (MacBook Air 2018). Is it still possible to get information about when the device has been booted? Is boot history stored somewhere on the mainboard?

Comment: _We all want to know for sure..._

Comment: The disk may contain unoverwritten data, but that requires reconstructing the files, as the file system metadata are gone.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, the disk has been formatted and overwritten three times.

Answer (score 7):

No. The only chip that stores static information is the BIOS chip and it does not store boot history

Comment: Good and simple answer. But what about UEFI?

Comment: UEFI is in a partition normally and has assistive boot information (logo, Q and A for booting, but not the history so far as I know

Comment: So i guess if HD is whipped and there's no component on the motherboard storing history, there is no possibility left (means boot history is not restorable), right?

Comment: Sadly, yes. If the HD is gone, you would need a backup to get your information.

Comment: @John Why "sadly"? Maybe the OP wants to hear this answer ;)

Comment: Not exactly correct... There's NVRAM on the RTC chip. It's availavle by means of UEFI protocol.